# What is the "Extract" token and how is the final Linear layer applied in GPT?

Tags: nlp, transformer, transfer-learning, gpt

In the manuscript of GPT, the authors have given the following image:

[image]

Questions:

1. What is the final "Extract" (token?)? Is it the "END" token?
2. How is the final linear layer applied? We would get a tensor of shape (N,L,D) out of the transformer (tranformer's final layer would itself be a pointwise feedforward) where N is the number of samples, L is the sequence length and D is the output dimension for every token. Taking just one sample it would be (1,L,D). How is the linear layer applied on top of this? The output of the final linear layer would have to be a vector with dimensions equal to the number of decisions at hand (n in case of n-way-classifier, vocabulary size in case of cloze task etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, the "extract" refers to the end of sequence token. We can see this in section 3.3 of the [original paper](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/openai-assets/research-covers/language-unsupervised/language_understanding_paper.pdf) (no idea why they called it "extract" in the figure):

   > All transformations include adding randomly initialized start and end tokens $(\langle s \rangle, \langle e \rangle)$.
2. The way they apply the final linear layer is described in section 3.2 of the original paper and consists of taking the output of the last Transformer layer $l$ at the last position ($h^m_l$ in the paper) and use it as input for the linear layer: $P(y|x^1, ..., x^m) = \mathit{softmax}(h^m_l W_y)$

Comment: I'm sorry for not being entirely clear in the second part of my question. My question is: Since I have one output vector from the transformer per token, how is the final linear layer applied. Let's take sentiment classification into positive, neutral and negative. Let's say my input in a sentence of 10 tokens. I would get (1, 10, 768) out of the transformer (1 sample, seq len 10 and 768 embed dim). What now? How is this (1,10,768) concerted to (1,3) (1 prob for each sentiment)?

Comment: Ahh, sorry for the misunderstanding. I amended my answer.

Comment: Thank you @noe. You have helped me earlier as well. My best wishes in everything :)